# Wordpress page and plugin list using sql query

Tags: plugins, wp-query, pages, mysql

I want to get all published pages and activated plugins of my word press site,i want all pages and plugin using mysql query.i don't want to copy paste all pages from wp admin.i want to get this list using mysql query.i just run this query on phpmyadmin and get list of pages and plugins

is this possible?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that, do you mean installed plugins? Activated plugins? Deactivated plugins? Published pages? Private pages? Trashed pages? You would get better results by editing this question to only ask for all pages, then opening a second question for all plugins, as they're both different questions with different answers. If you want a single SQL query that does both, that's not possible, and where plugins are concerned, what you mean by all plugins means an SQL query may or may not be possible

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes,Activated plugins and  Published pages,Not single query,i need both list Activated plugins and  Published pages

Comment: So ***"From MySQL, how would I query all published pages, and all activated plugins on a single site?"***